# Ошибка при использовании регулярных выражений: TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python, функции

Необходимо выяснить какому оператору принадлежит номер.
Если код оператора не известен - вернуть `unknown`.

- Мегафон, если начинается с `8921` и длина цифр 11 или 7.
- Билайн, если начинается с `8952` и длина цифр 11 или 12.
- МТS, если начинается с `8929`, `8911`, `8930` и длина цифр 11 .
- Неизвестно, если начинается `8900` и другие и длины цифр другие.

Пример:

- Вход: `89211111111`. Выход: `Megafon`.
- Вход: `89521111111`. Выход: `Beeline`.
- Вход: `89291111111`. Выход: `МТS`.
- Вход: `89001111111`. Выход: `unknown`.

Сам думал в этом ключе:

```
import re
num = input('Enter number: ')

if len(num) == 11 or len(num) == 7:
    for num in re.match(8921):
        print('Megafon')
if len(num) == 11 or len(num) == 12:
    for num in re.match(8952) :
        print('Beeline')
if len(num) == 11:
    for num in re.match(8929):
        print('MTS')
    else:
        print('unknown')
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/zzz/Python/search_number.py", line 5, in 
>       for num in re.match(8921): TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: Простите, а для чего сие, если не секрет? Сейчас определить по коду к какому оператору привязана симка практически невозможно с учетом возможности перевода номера на другого оператора связи.

Comment: Приветствую, не секрет. Изучаю Пайтон на практике так сказать, задачу сам придумал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

num = input('Enter number: ')
if not isinstance(num, str):
    num = str(num)

def f(exp, word):
    return bool(re.search(exp, word))

if f('^8926\d{7}', num):
    print 'Megafon'
elif f('^8952\d{7,8}', num):
    print 'Beeline'
elif f('^8929\d{7}', num) or f('^8911\d{7}', num) or f('^8930\d{7}', num):
    print 'MTS'
else:
    print 'unknown'
```

Comment: Спасибо, за Ваш ответ! Если не затруднит, добавьте в него ограничения по длине и поисковым префиксам согласно задаче.

Answer (score 1):

У вас 3 ошибки в строках как

```
    for num in re.match(8921):
```

Первый параметр функции `re.match()` нужен быть *строкой* (в апострофах или кавычках), нужно тоже второго параметра - `num` и вместо `for num in` должно быть просто `if`:

```
    if re.match('8921', num):
```

**Добавление:**

Ещё лучше, как показал [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) в комментарии - заменить эту команду командой

```
    if num.startswith('8921'):
```

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо вам, я добавил ваш ценный совет в мой ответ.

Comment: @MaxU это неверно. match() смотрит только на начало строки. Не путайте match() и search(). Сравните: `re.match('start', 'start found')` и `re.match('start', 'not found start')`

Comment: @jfs, да, действительно неправильно сказал - удалил комментарий...